# How much do C/C++ compilers optimize conditional statements?

Tags: c++, c

I recently ran into a situation where I wrote the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (size - 1); i++)
{
    // do whatever
}

// Assume 'size' will be constant during the duration of the for loop
```

When looking at this code, it made me wonder how exactly the for loop condition is evaluated for each loop. Specifically, I'm curious as to whether or not the compiler would 'optimize away' any additional arithmetic that has to be done for each loop. In my case, would this code get compiled such that (size - 1) would have to be evaluated for every loop iteration? Or is the compiler smart enough to realize that the 'size' variable won't change, thus it could precalculate it for each loop iteration.

This then got me thinking about the general case where you have a conditional statement that may specify more operations than necessary.

As an example, how would the following two pieces of code compile:

```
if(6)

if(1+1+1+1+1+1)

int foo = 1;
if(foo + foo + foo + foo + foo + foo)
```

How smart is the compiler? Will the 3 cases listed above be converted into the same machine code?

And while I'm at, why not list another example. What does the compiler do if you are doing an operation within a conditional that won't have any effect on the end result? Example:

```
if(2*(val))

// Assume val is an int that can take on any value
```

In this example, the multiplication is completely unnecessary. While this case seems a lot stupider than my original case, the question still stands: will the compiler be able to remove this unnecessary multiplication?

Question:

- How much optimization is involved with conditional statements?
- Does it vary based on compiler?

Comment: _How much optimization_ isn't answerable. What are expecting? A percent? 50% optimization? A subjective term like "lots"?

Comment: @Tas Come on man, it's an open question. Commenting on some of the examples I listed would be more than enough.

Comment: Tell your compiler to generate an assembly language listing.  Usually a compare or conditional statement is 2 assembly language statements:  compare and branch.

Comment: For `if (2*(val))`, note that the multiplication can be removed if `val` is an `int` (because overflow is undefined), but not if it's an `unsigned int`, because it may wrap to 0.

Comment: @Tas In the future, pleas refer to responses like what Gavin Haynes posted. The answer comments on some of the posted questions, and then provides a link to further discussion.

Comment: @Teague: In the future: (a) don't bite the hand that feeds you; (b) don't school the people you're asking for help; (c) listen to the questions posed, because they aren't posed for fun. They are posed either to genuinely clarify your question or, more likely, to make a very important point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ language specification permits the compiler to make any optimization that results in no observable changes to the expected results.

If the compiler can determine that `size` is constant and will not change during execution, it can certainly make that particular optimization.

Alternatively, if the compiler can also determine that `i` is not used in the loop (and its value is not used afterwards), that it is used only as a counter, it might very well rewrite the loop to:

```
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
```

because that might produce smaller code. Even if this `i` is used in some fashion, the compiler can still make this change and then adjust all other usage of `i` so that the observable results are still the same.

To summarize: anything goes. The compiler may or may not make any optimization change as long as the observable results are the same.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: the compiler is *exceptionally* clever, and will generally optimise those cases that you have presented (including utterly ignoring irrelevant conditions).

One of the biggest hurdles language newcomers face in terms of *truly* understanding C++, is that there is not a one-to-one relationship between their code and what the computer executes. The entire purpose of the language is to create an **abstraction**. You are defining the program's semantics, but the computer has no responsibility to actually follow your C++ code line by line; indeed, if it did so, it would be abhorrently slow as compared to the speed we can expect from modern computers.

Generally speaking, unless you have a reason to micro-optimise (game developers come to mind), it is best to almost completely *ignore* this facet of programming, and trust your compiler. Write a program that takes the inputs you want, and gives the outputs you want, after performing the calculations you want… and let your compiler do the hard work of figuring out how the physical machine is going to make all that happen.

Are there exceptions? Certainly. Sometimes your requirements are so specific that you do know better than the compiler, and you end up optimising. You generally do this after profiling and determining what your bottlenecks are. And there's also no excuse to write deliberately silly code. After all, if you go out of your way to ask your program to copy a 50MB vector, then it's going to copy a 50MB vector.

But, assuming sensible code that means what it looks like, you really shouldn't spend too much time worrying about this. Because modern compilers are *so good* at optimising, that you'd be a fool to try to keep up.

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, there is a lot of optimization, and it is very complex.
- It varies based on the compiler, and it also varies based on the compiler options

Check 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25840/can-we-stop-recommending-the-dragon-book-please
for some book recomendations if you really want to understand what a compiler may do. It is a very complex subject.

You can also compile to assembly with the `-S` option (gcc / g++) to see what the compiler is really doing. Use `-O3` / ... / `-O0` / `-O` to experiment with different optimization levels.